# compare 2 excel based on server name and get data from one file

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having below 2 excel files (Sample data)

**File_1**

```
Server        System                Sub-System V2.0             OS        Virtual   Normal/Project  Cloud_Type        DRP
MAH1DB        000 -Infrastructure   000-001-Service-P           Windows   Virtual   Normal          VMware Cloud    Full VM DRP
```

**File_2**

```
VM        VM Name     PowerState    CPUs
MAH1DB  000_MAH1DB    PoweredOn       8
```

I want to compare both the files based on **VM** (**Server in File_1 and VM in File_2**). If matches, need to get 3 columns **System,Sub-System V2.0,DRP**  from **File_1** and add as column in **File_2**

So the expected output in **File_2** will be

```
VM        VM Name     PowerState    CPUs  System                Sub-System V2.0    DRP
MAH1DB  000_MAH1DB    PoweredOn       8   000 -Infrastructure   000-001-Service-P  Full VM DRP
```

I was trying to do like below, but not getting how to proceed further

```
$FilePath = "C:\March 2023 V1-2.xlsx"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$data_1 = $wb.Worksheets['Servers'].UsedRange.Rows.Columns[1].Value2
$wb.close()
$xl.Quit()

###################

$FilePath = "C:\Raw.xlsx"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$data_2 = $wb.Worksheets['Sheet1'].UsedRange.Rows.Columns[1].Value2
$wb.close()
$xl.Quit()


foreach($svr_1 in $data_1)
{
    foreach($svr_2 in $data_2)
    {
        if($svr_1 -match $svr_2)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

What I was planning was to read the server names from both the sheet, if matches then get the respective columns from **$File_1** and append in **File_2**

Please let me know how can I do this

Comment: It looks like you're copying only the value of _one_ column from the worksheet. Please clarify the exact data type / format of what is contained in `$data_1` and `$data_2`. Note that the sample data given is neither tab-separated nor suggests (properly aligned) fixed-width columns.

Comment: @mklement0: these are 2 different file contents. the data provided is only a sample excel data I have pasted here. **$data1** and **$data2** here contains the server/VM names from both the files

Comment: Understood, but my question was about the _specific data format_ contained in `$data_1` and `$data_2` (array of strings? a single, multiline string? tab-separated fields? ...). Knowing that is the prerequisite for parsing the input into _objects_ that can then be joined by shared _property values_. That your question hasn't received answers in 2 days suggests that it is under-specified.

Comment: @mklement0: sorry. my bad then. the data is both contains newline separated data.
like 
`
a
b
c
`